# Discrete Math - Recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

When I read this question, I have no idea how to approach it. Can someone break down the steps to solving this question?

Let $Σ = \{a, b, c\}$. Find a recurrence for the number of length $n$ strings in $Σ^∗$ that do not contain any two consecutive $a$’s, $b$’s, nor c’s (i.e. none of $aa$, $bb$, nor $cc$ are in the string).

So this is what I have done so far:
[My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkPdy.jpg)

I have completed the problem and here is the solution:
[My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahGDK.jpg)

THANK YOU to everyone who helped, or even looked at this post. Special kudos to @JMoravitz for his kind help!

Comment: Tianlalu, what was the edit?

Comment: It is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Notice... There are three length $1$ strings (*and one length $0$ string*).  The final character of any string of length greater than $1$ must be different than the character just before it.  Worded differently, given a string of a particular length, if you want to extend it to be one character longer, you can append either of the two available characters to the end.

Comment: @JMoravitz I completely understand what you mean. So in that case we can just keep adding a different character and make a new string. Therefore, we could keep going to infinity. But how would I go about this specific problem.

Comment: If you have $f(n)$ number of strings of length $n$... can you come up with a relationship between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$?  If you have... say... $12$ strings of length $3$... how many strings would there be of length $4$ knowing this and knowing that any string of length $3$ may be turned into a string of length $4$ in two different ways by tacking on an extra character at the end?

Comment: I think the question is posed in non-standard syntax, but reading between the lines I'm quite certain that  $ \Sigma ^*$ must be referring to the set of all strings whose characters are elements of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean @JMoravitz. Please check out my edit, I linked an image to my work.

Comment: There are more than nine valid strings of length $3$.

Comment: @WW1 That is correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz like aba? would that count?

Comment: $\color{blue}{ab}a,~ \color{blue}{ab}c,~\color{red}{ac}a, \color{red}{ac}b,~ \color{green}{ba}b, \color{green}{ba}c, \dots$.  You should see a pattern here.  Note... noone wants or expects you to find too many values of the sequence by hand, it is not worth the effort to manually find the values by brute force counting... but getting enough of the values might help you spot the pattern.  Your end goal is to come up with a way of expressing $f(n+1)$ as a function in terms of $f(n)$ (*or lower terms if necessary*)

Comment: Thank you for your diligent efforts man. This is making sense. I'm going to have to write out more values and see the pattern. I'll come back here once I figure it out ;)

Comment: The recursion you are looking for is only valid for $n \ge 1$, You don't need to make the $n=0$ case fit the pattern.

Comment: @WW1 I was thinking about exactly the same thing! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three valid strings of length $1$.  They are namely $a,b,c$.  For each of these, there are two possible ways to continue them into a length $2$ string:

$$a \mapsto \begin{cases} ab\\ac\end{cases}$$

$$b\mapsto \begin{cases} ba\\bc\end{cases}$$

$$c\mapsto \begin{cases} ca\\cb\end{cases}$$

Now... for each of these six length two strings there are two ways to continue each into a length three string:

$$ab\mapsto\begin{cases}aba\\abc\end{cases}$$

$$ac\mapsto\begin{cases}aca\\acb\end{cases}$$

$$ba\mapsto\begin{cases}bab\\bac\end{cases}$$

$$\vdots$$

Notice, in the above process, there are no repeats.  Convince yourself of this.

In general, given a valid length $n$ string, we may extend it in two ways to make a valid length $n+1$ string.

Convince yourself that every valid length $n+1$ string is uniquely comprised of a prefix made of a length $n$ string followed by suffix made of a single character which is different than the final character of the prefix.

Convince yourself then that supposing we know the number of valid length $n$ strings is $f(n)$, we can use this information and this information alone to calculate $f(n+1)$.

> (*There is one valid length $0$ string*).  There are three length $1$ strings.  There are six length $2$ strings.  There are twelve length $3$ strings, etc...

$~$

You are tasked with coming up with an equation for $f(n+1)$ which depends only on the value of $f(n)$ (*or in some later problems it could also depend on $f(n-1),f(n-2),\dots$*) and possibly some constants.  Additionally, if you are tasked with it, you might be further asked to find a closed form for the function which avoids the necessity of referring to earlier values.

Comment: This makes so much sense! Thank you!